# How to filter a table in a tooltip when clicking a sheet in a dashboard?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard and when I click on each sheet, the other sheets are filtered. I have a table in a tooltip and I would like this also to be filtered to what was clicked in the other sheet. How to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if the tooltip worksheet is included in the dashboard, it will be filtered out. I just need to find a way to hide it from the dashboard but right now, it works as intended if added in the dashboard.

Update: Float the sheet in the dashboard and resize it to make it invisible